# Flask-SQLAlchemy Query Cost - Unicode Conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, python-2.7, unicode, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to databases, and I am trying to speed up my queries in a Flask-SQLalchemy (Python 2.7) application. I have profiled the code, but am lost as to how to interpret it. I would love more general tips on this subject, but my specific question is this: the "string_decoder" execution time of the query seems very costly, and I assume that it is converting strings to unicode so that it can return them in unicode format.

```
  259619 function calls (259567 primitive calls) in 1.108 seconds                                                                                                                      

   Ordered by: cumulative time                                                                                                                                                                

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)                                                                                                                       
    1    0.007    0.007    1.108    1.108 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:2235(all)                                                                        
 5947    0.019    0.000    0.651    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py:27(instances)                                                                  
 5946    0.116    0.000    0.515    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py:323(_instance)                                                                 
    1    0.000    0.000    0.449    0.449 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:2348(__iter__)                                                                   
    1    0.000    0.000    0.448    0.448 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:2362(_execute_and_instances)                                                     
    1    0.000    0.000    0.448    0.448 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:597(execute)                                                                   
    1    0.000    0.000    0.448    0.448 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:727(_execute_clauseelement)                                                    
    1    0.000    0.000    0.446    0.446 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:812(_execute_context)                                                          
    1    0.000    0.000    0.445    0.445 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:323(do_execute)                                                             
    1    0.000    0.000    0.445    0.445 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py:164(execute)                                                                          
    1    0.000    0.000    0.445    0.445 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py:343(_query)                                                                           
    1    0.000    0.000    0.427    0.427 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py:348(_post_get_result)                                                                 
    1    0.000    0.000    0.427    0.427 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py:314(_fetch_row)                                                                       
    1    0.068    0.068    0.427    0.427 {built-in method fetch_row}                                                                                                                     
 5946    0.092    0.000    0.231    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py:280(populate_state)                                                            
12547    0.040    0.000    0.208    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py:206(string_decoder)                                                               
12547    0.053    0.000    0.168    0.000 {method 'decode' of 'str' objects}                                                                                                              
 5946    0.121    0.000    0.152    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/times.py:44(DateTime_or_None)                                                                    
12547    0.064    0.000    0.115    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py:15(decode)                                                                                                
53514    0.086    0.000    0.086    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py:150(fetch_col)                                                              
 5946    0.038    0.000    0.085    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py:286(new_instance)                                                      
    1    0.037    0.037    0.070    0.070 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py:505(_commit_all_states)                                                          
 5946    0.015    0.000    0.052    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py:619(reset_for_lazy_callable)                                                
12547    0.051    0.000    0.051    0.000 {_codecs.utf_8_decode}                                                                                                                          
 5946    0.028    0.000    0.037    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/identity.py:107(add)                                                                      
 5946    0.023    0.000    0.037    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py:285(_reset)                                                                      
17838    0.031    0.000    0.031    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}                                                                                                               
    2    0.018    0.009    0.029    0.014 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py:687(unique_list)                                                         
 5946    0.027    0.000    0.027    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py:44(__init__)
```

However, I do not need this to happen. I don't need the strings to be in unicode format, typical ASCII or python 'str' types would be just fine. I cannot figure out how to get rid of this, or why I would need it. I may be missing something.

Finally, could someone confirm that the overall time required to retrieve 6k rows, which is over one second, is really slow? This seems way too long to me, but I don't have much to base it off of.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing driving your query time is that you're getting 6000 rows. Do you really need all columns of all 6000 rows? The decode is taking less than 1/5 of the total time. Trying to micro-optimise that away is probably a waste of time. Thinking about the data that you need to move around and getting the database to do the heavy lifting is probably a better use of your time.

Comment: Even grabbing 350 rows and just one column, the query is still very slow, on the order of 1/3 of a second. A raw SQL query grabs the rows in 0.01 seconds.